# How to multiply first two digit in a single dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, multiplication

I have tried many ways in doing this but it doesn't work for my case. Many of them are multiplied by columns, for my case is need to get the first two digit from a single column and multiply.

[this is a column in a dataset and I need to get the first two-digit and multiply with each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj6jC.png)
For example: for the first row I need to get 4 multiply by 5 and the result will store in a new column

May I know how to do it?

Thank you in advanced^^

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For following dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
d={'locationID':[12,234,34]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
print(data)
   locationID
0    12
1   234
2    34
```

## If you want to multiply all the digits

function to multiply all the digits,

```
def multiplyall(number):
  result=1
  for i in range(len(str(number))):
    result=int(str(number)[i])*result    
  return result
```

create column and add values according to the function in one line with `insert(location, column name, column values)`

```
data.insert(len(data.columns), 'new_column', data['locationID'].apply(lambda x: multiply_all(x)).tolist())
```

you'll get the following output

```
print(data)
   locationID  new_column
0      12           2
1     234          24
2      34          12
```

## If you want to multiply ONLY 1st and 2nd digits

function to multiply 1st and 2nd digits,

```
def multiply_firstsecond(number):
  result=number
  if len(str(number))>1:
    result=int(str(number)[0])* int(str(number)[1])
  return result
```

Similarly,

```
data.insert(len(data.columns), 'new_column', data['locationID'].apply(lambda x: multiply_firstsecond(x)).tolist())
```

output for this one,

```
print(data)
   locationID  new_column
0      12           2
1     234           6
2      34          12
```

PLEASE make sure you have no `NaN` or non-numeric values in the column to avoid errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation of it!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ID = ['45.0',
      '141.0',
      '191.0',
      '143.0',
      '243.0']

N = [f"{int(s[0])*int(s[1])}" for s in ID]

print(N)
```

Output:

```
['20',
 '4',
 '9',
 '4',
 '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
data = DataFrame([
    (54423),
    (2023),
    (4353),
    (76754)
], columns=["number_1"])

data["number_2"] = 0

def calculation(num):
    mult = num
    if len(str(num)) >= 2:
        str_num = str(num)
        mult = int(str_num[0]) * int(str_num[1])
    return mult
        
data["number_2"] = data["number_1"].apply(calculation)
print(data)

  number_1  number_2
0     54423        20
1      2023         0
2      4353        12
3     76754        42
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this literally works on my situation.=)